# WPF ToolTip flickers

Tags: c#, wpf

I've defined a toolTip over a dataGrid in the following way:

> ```
> <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
>  <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
>   <Setter Property="ToolTip" >
>    <Setter.Value>
>      <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Value.TimeStamps}"></ListBox>   
>    </Setter.Value>
>   </Setter>
>  </Style>
> </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
> ```

But the tool tip flickers and it's hard to read the content.
How to solve the issue?

****edit:
the binding is to an ObservableDictionary, the key and value are both a ViewModel

The value has the following property

```
>    #region timeStamps
>         /// <summary>
>         /// The <see cref="TimeStamps" /> property's name.
>         /// </summary>
>         public const string TimeStampsPropertyName = "TimeStamps";
> 
>         private ObservableCollection<String> _timeStamps = new ObservableCollection<string>();
> 
>         /// <summary>
>         /// Sets and gets the TimeStamps property.
>         /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
>         /// </summary>
>         public ObservableCollection<String> TimeStamps
>         {
>             get
>             {
>                 return _timeStamps;
>             }
>             set
>             {
>                 Set(TimeStampsPropertyName, ref _timeStamps, value);
>             }
>         }
>         #endregion
```

This is the property that should be displayed in the Tooltip.

Comment: Can you add `Value.TimeStamps` code to the description? I think that the problem will be there.

Comment: What's the code where you're setting the TimeStamps values? Share a more complete, verifiable demo.